# How can I scale movement physics functions to frames per second (in a game engine)?

Tags: javascript, physics, game-engine, game-physics

I am working on a game in Javascript (HTML5 Canvas). I implemented a simple algorithm that allows an object to follow another object with basic physics mixed in (a force vector to drive the object in the right direction, and the velocity stacks momentum, but is slowed by a constant drag force). At the moment, I set it up as a rectangle following the mouse (x, y) coordinates. Here's the code:

```
// rectangle x, y position
var x = 400; // starting x position
var y = 250; // starting y position
var FPS = 60; // frames per second of the screen
// physics variables:
var velX = 0; // initial velocity at 0 (not moving)
var velY = 0; // not moving
var drag = 0.92; // drag force reduces velocity by 8% per frame
var force = 0.35; // overall force applied to move the rectangle
var angle = 0; // angle in which to move

// called every frame (at 60 frames per second):
function update(){
    // calculate distance between mouse and rectangle
    var dx = mouseX - x;
    var dy = mouseY - y;
    // calculate angle between mouse and rectangle
    var angle = Math.atan(dy/dx);
    if(dx < 0)
        angle += Math.PI;
    else if(dy < 0)
        angle += 2*Math.PI;

    // calculate the force (on or off, depending on user input)
    var curForce;
    if(keys[32]) // SPACE bar
        curForce = force; // if pressed, use 0.35 as force
    else
        curForce = 0; // otherwise, force is 0

    // increment velocty by the force, and scaled by drag for x and y
    velX += curForce * Math.cos(angle);
    velX *= drag;
    velY += curForce * Math.sin(angle);
    velY *= drag;

    // update x and y by their velocities
    x += velX;
    y += velY;
```

And that works fine at 60 frames per second. Now, the tricky part: my question is, if I change this to a different framerate (say, 30 FPS), how can I modify the force and drag values to keep the movement constant?

That is, right now my rectangle (whose position is dictated by the x and y variables) moves at a maximum speed of about 4 pixels per second, and accelerates to its max speed in about 1 second. BUT, if I change the framerate, it moves slower (e.g. 30 FPS accelerates to only 2 pixels per frame).

So, how can I create an equation that takes FPS (frames per second) as input, and spits out correct "drag" and "force" values that will behave the same way in real time?

I know it's a heavy question, but perhaps somebody with game design experience, or knowledge of programming physics can help. Thank you for your efforts.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BadDB

Comment: I removed my answer since it's clearly not correct, looking at the fiddle. I'm not sure _why_ it's not right, though, sorry. It might be because of the "physics" implementation (for instance, you're not actually using kinematic equations, AIUI).

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of a sketchy implementation. It's my first time trying to play with simulated physics, so it's not pretty. Regardless, thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

I would introduce an actual time measure. You should then rework your equations to be functions of actual elapsed time and desired maximum speed. The benefit of using actual elapsed time is that the equations will work well even on systems that (because of load or what-have-you) don't operate at the programmed FPS.

As an aside -- you should be using `Math.atan2(dy, dx)` instead of `Math.atan(dy/dx)`. (Think what happens when `dx == 0`.)

Comment: For the record, JavaScript's `Math.atan(1/0)` correctly returns `pi/2` (since `1/0` is `Infinity` instead of throwing some sort of DivideByZeroError), so you don't need `atan2()` for that. What `atan2` _does_ get you is correct quadrant handling for arguments like `Math.atan2(-1, -1)`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Motivation

Comment: @MattBall - Good point about Infinity. I guess my Fortran days are showing. :)

Comment: The only caveat here is that this will make your actual results dependent on the speed of the machine being used. For example, a collision between two charged particles will come up with different answers if you assume, say, linear motion between frames. So if you need the result to be independent of the frame rate you have to be very careful about the path of an object. Also floating point errors will accumulate differently, and you end up with a chaotic sensitivity to the frame rate.

Comment: @PhilH - Agreed. With actual time measure, the physics simulation will be dependent on machine speed. On the other hand, if one assumes that each animation cycle is always one unit of time, the game experience will be dependent on machine speed. (Time will pass slower on a slower machine.) However, OP describes fairly simple physics, and the problem to be solved is exactly that the game experience varies with frame rate.

Answer (score 1):

What you should ideally be doing is taking your timeframe as time elapsed since the previous frame, then calculating a scale-factor based on the actual delta, and using that for time-based calculations.

Consider that ideally, your game is running at 60fps.
Also consider that really, your game will rarely run at exactly 1000ms/60f for EVERY single frame of gameplay.

So your ideal would be `1000/60`.
Your actual would be `current_timestamp - previous_timestamp`.
Your timeframe's scale would be `actual/ideal`.

Now, you just need to use your scale to transform your time-sensitive values.

Anything which is a function of time can use its "ideal-value-per-frame" (`magnitude = 8; current_magnitude = magnitude * scale; vec.x *= current_magnitude; vec.y *= current_magnitude; vec.z *= current_magnitude;`).

You just need to be careful to understand when to multiply and when not to.
If a calculation is time-based, then pre-multiply.  If it isn't, then don't.

If your game is running at 15fps, your time-scale is going to be 4x, right?
That shouldn't affect the power of anything.  It wouldn't affect, say, the torque of a car -- the pent-up energy the engine is building.  What it ***would*** affect is how much acceleration (linear or otherwise) happens within that exact span of time.

If the car should accelerate by 0.5m/s^2, or whatever you're deciding, then you're looking at just the fraction of that acceleration (being added onto the current speed), which applies to the particular fraction of the second you're currently in.
Then in the next update, the car should travel at that speed you've set, multiplied by the time-scale you calculate as the difference between the current frame and the previous at that point.

Rotations should be calculated the same way.

This allows you to separate inconsistent framerates from actual actions, as you're always operating based on percentages, rather than on hard numbers (where time is involved).

This also allows for things like bullet-time to be done stupidly easily.
Add an added bullet-time factor to ***everything***, except aiming.
Or if you want to make a ninja-reflex-whatever, apply different time-scales to the player, versus the enemies.

For freezing time, you'd have two options:

1. set everything to 0 and forget the values before (let everything accrue momentum from 0, on resume)
2. set everything to 0 but keep a "frame" of all of the values previous.  Forget the 0s afterwards, but treat the next span of time as if only 1 frame has passed since the pause happened.

When you're talking about what to do regarding `drag` -- you said it yourself: `drag` is a `constant` in your simulation.
It doesn't matter how long a span of time or how short a span of time you're talking about, the effect that the drag had on an object in that span of time is consistent with how it will affect any object in any other span of time.

Answer (score 0):

Double the force and leave drag unchanged.

**EDIT:**

The math:

The motion can be fully described by two parameters: initial acceleration and terminal velocity. If those two look right, the motion will look right.

For initial acceleration, drag (this kind of drag) doesn't matter. Since `force` is an acceleration, all we have to do is add it up for as many frames are in a second, to get one second's woth of acceleration:

force<sub>30</sub> * 30 = force<sub>60</sub> * 60
force<sub>30</sub> = force<sub>60</sub> * 60/30 = 2.0 * force<sub>60</sub> = 2.0 (0.35) = 0.7

Terminal velocity occurs when force and drag are balanced.

V<sub>term</sub> * drag = force
drag = force / V<sub>term</sub>

We want to scale V<sub>term</sub>, but we're also scaling `force`, so the scale terms cancel; `drag` need not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Integral of force is velocity and integral of velocity is position when you are doing integration in terms of **time**. If you make your time-step equal to the time between two frames, your bullet-physics will work if you have a post-collision detector.

Time between two frames is inversely related to FPS.

FPS = total frames / total time

Time step=( 1.0/(float)FPS seconds )*K.   K is a constant to make your timestep small enough so your physics is stable enough.